# iOS Swift: Move focus from one textfield to another

Tags: ios, swift, textfield, becomefirstresponder

I'm developing an iOS App that uses a PageViewController to wrap several "Chat rooms". I've a TextField in each page and when I swipe in order to move to another page I wanna change the focus from the current page TextField to the new page TextField without losing the keyboard.

I've tried different approaches but I cannot do that, every time I call becomeFirstResponder in the new page TextField the keyboard goes down, then goes up immediately and then the textfields becomes the first responder.

Can you help me?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you calling `resignFirstResponder` on the old text field? If you are, don't.

Comment: Nop. I'm not using resignFirstResponder at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find a solution for this problem:

Using a variable in each page

```
var firstResponderIsLocked: Bool = false
```

To check if the TextField should end editing

```
func textFieldShouldEndEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    return !firstResponderIsLocked
}
```

And handling it when I swipe between pages:

```
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, willTransitionToViewControllers pendingViewControllers: [UIViewController]) {
    if let viewControllerToShow = pendingViewControllers[0] as? LiveMessagingPageContentViewController {
        pendingViewControllerIndex = viewControllerToShow.index
        lockFirstResponder(pendingViewControllerIndex!)
    }
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
    if completed && pendingViewControllerIndex != nil {
        takeFirstResponder(pendingViewControllerIndex!)
    }
    pendingViewControllerIndex = nil
}
```

I make my app work as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Put the text field on the page view controller's view, instead of on each child page. From the page view controller, call `self.view.bringSubviewToFront(textField)` to put it on top.

I just tested this in a new project (using the "Page-Based Application" template) and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks for your awnser jrc. That's a valid solution, but I need to have a textfield in each child page because I don't wanna lose the text entered in the textfield when I change to another page (I could probably save the text in a child page variable also, but I found ok my current solution)